# WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-4.2.0) - gateway-worker Not Starting Up Properly

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2am-4.2.0 and I am trying to startup one node as an all-in-one-instance and another as a gateway-worker node using Docker.
However, the gateway-worker node fails to startup and the following error appears in the wso2carbon.log.

```
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]} - Exception starting filter [CaptchaFilter] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4609)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5248)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN mkdir -p <APIM_HOME>
RUN mkdir -p <JAVA_HOME>
COPY ./wso2am-4.2.0.zip <APIM_HOME>
COPY ./jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz <JAVA_HOME>
RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
RUN yum install unzip -y
RUN yum install tar -y
RUN cd <APIM_HOME>/bin/ && ./profileSetup.sh -Dprofile=gateway-worker
RUN cd <JAVA_HOME>/java/ && tar -xvf jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
RUN rm -f <APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml
EXPOSE 8243 8280 9443
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "<APIM_HOME>/bin/api-manager.sh -Dprofile=gateway-worker"]
```

deployment.toml

```
[server]
hostname = "<HOSTNAME>"
node_ip = "<IP>"
offset=50
server_role = "gateway-worker"

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "<DB_URL>"
username = ""
password = ""

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "wso2carbon"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[truststore]
file_name = "client-truststore.jks"
type = "JKS"
password = "wso2carbon"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

# key manager implementation
[apim.key_manager]
service_url = "https://Node1:9483/services/"

# Traffic Manager configurations
[apim.throttling]
service_url = "https://Node1:9483/services/"
throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://Node1:5712"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls=["tcp://Node1:9651"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls=["ssl://Node1:9751"]
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your WSO2 distribution could be corrupted. Can you start the docker image without any config changes?

Comment: Hi @ycr, I used the following command to build the zip file using Maven. mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true and the generated zip file is used each time the docker build command is run which refers the Dockerfile to build the image. The same distribution starts up properly when the server role is pasased as server_role = "Default" in the deployment.toml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you have not optimized the distribution for the worker profile. Once you create the APIM distribution you need to run the profile optimization script in order to remove unnecessary components which don't belong to each profile. There are two ways to do this, before starting the server and while starting the server, the better approach is the first approach.

**Option 1**

```bash
sh <API-M_HOME>/bin/profileSetup.sh  -Dprofile=<preferred-profile>
```

**Option 2**

```bash
sh <PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/api-manager.sh --optimize -Dprofile=<preferred-profile> --skipConfigOptimization
```

Also, note once you run the profile optimization script the `deployment.toml` will also be optimized, so you can use the optimized `deployment.toml` template when configuring each profile.
Documentation [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/).

Comment: now the following exception is seen in the container log when starting up and therefore, fails to startup the server completely. {"log":"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/WEB-INF/web.xml (No such file or directory)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2023-08-07T18:27:23.733036581Z"}

Comment: Did you start the server with the `-Dprofile` profile flag?

Comment: yes I did. I included it in the Dockerfile and used it to build the image.